# Running into selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: when trying to click a button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to webscrape Balance Sheet data from Yahoo finance (https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/balance-sheet?p=MSFT). Specifically, the Current Assets, Total Non Current Assets, Total Non Current Liabilities Net Minority Interest, and Current Liabilities values. I am able to click on the Total Assets dropdown button and get the values for Current Assets and Non Current assets but I get a `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted:` ... `</button> is not clickable at point (39, 592). Other element would receive the click: <div tabindex="1" class="lightbox-wrapper Ta(c) Pos(f) T(0) Start(0) H(100%) W(100%) Bgc($modalBackground) Ovy(a) Z(50) Op(1)">...</div>` when I try to click on Total Liabilities Net Minority Interest to get Total Non Current Liabilities Net Minority Interest and Current Liabilities. This is my current approach:

```
# Clicks button based on button text (For example, Current Assets)
def clickButtonByText(driver, url, button_text):
    driver.get(url)
    button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'//button[@aria-label="{button_text}"]'))).click()
    time.sleep(10)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    return soup
```

```
# Assume getDriver() returns a singleton WebDriver
def readBalanceSheetRow():

    # This works fine to get the Current Assets and Non Current Assets
    html_response = clickButtonByText(getDriver(), 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/balance-sheet?p=MSFT', 'Total Assets')

    # This is where I get selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException
    html_response_two = clickButtonByText(getDriver(), 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/balance-sheet?p=MSFT', 'Total Liabilities Net Minority Interest')
```

Not sure why I am running into an issue when dealing with Total Liabilities Net Minority Interest since both Total Liabilities Net Minority Interest and Total Assets seem to be structured the same way in html. Does anyone know why I am running into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try performing the `click()` action on desired element using Java script's `execute_script()` method.

Instead of below line:

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'//button[@aria-label="{button_text}"]'))).click()
```

Change it to:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//button[@aria-label="{button_text}"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```